# How to play multiple audio files simultaneously with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a web app that lets the user play back multiple tracks of a song.
Instead of one file for the whole mix, each track has been exported separately and I am trying to find the code that would allow multiple audio flew to begin playing from only clicking one button.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) is a jQuery HTML5 library that can do that for you.